# Is there a way I can make woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link not change url address but still add product to cart?

Tags: php, url, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, cart

Is there a way I can still add/remove a product to my cart without the page url changing?

I have custom add to cart button on my custom Wordpress theme but as I add product to cart the url changes to http://localhost/mytheme/?add-to-cart=15. Is there a way I can avoid it and still add product to the cart?

```
<?php global $product;

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
    sprintf( '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="addtocart_nupp">Add product</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        $product->is_purchasable() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
        esc_attr( $product->get_type() ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce has a hook `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` which is called when you add a product to your cart.

There are two arguments which you get `$url` where it is redirecting and `$product` which was added to your cart.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'bks_add_to_cart_redirect', 10, 2 );
function bks_add_to_cart_redirect( $url, $product ) {
    if ( $product && is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        // Do any change or URL you want to $url.
    }
    return $url;
}
```

---

You can change the logic and redirect it back to the product page by changing $url inside if like so.

```
$url = esc_url($product->get_permalink());
```

You can add paramters to it.

```
$url = esc_url( add_query_arg('name', 'value', $product->get_permalink() ) );
```

-- OR --

Just redirect it to a custom page.

```
$url = esc_url( home_url() . '/custom_page' );
```